# How to aggregate data for mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item_id" : 1, "parent_id" : null, count: 10},
{ "_id" : 2, "item_id" : 2, "parent_id" : 1,    count: 20},
{ "_id" : 3, "item_id" : 3, "parent_id" : null, count: 30},
{ "_id" : 4, "item_id" : 4, "parent_id" : 1,    count: 40}
```

If I find items with `count > 0`, I should get items:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item_id" : 1, "parent_id" : null, count: 10},
{ "_id" : 3, "item_id" : 3, "parent_id" : null, count: 30}
```

We didn't get items 2, 4 because they are childs for item 1

If I find items with `count > 15`, I should get items:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "item_id" : 2, "parent_id" : 1,    count: 20},
{ "_id" : 3, "item_id" : 3, "parent_id" : null, count: 30}
```

Item 2 is the first child item in conditions, item 3 is an item in conditions

So if I have parent items I should skip child, but if I have only children I should get only the first child.

It should work with pagination and sorting.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me it seems not yet clear, what behaviour do you *expect* and which is the *actual* behaviour you observe? It would be helpful if you could make that a bit clearer.

Comment: So in the collection I can have parent items (parent_id === null) and child items (parent_id > 0). If we try to find by condition count > 0 in normal query we'll get all items, but I need: if we have parent items in this condition we skip child items. So for this condition we'll get items 1 and 3. If we  If we try to find by condition count > 15 parent item 1 not in this condition so we should get first child items. So we'll get items 2 and 3. but all this conditions should work in one query with sorting, limit, skip and etc

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `find()` method is an object describing which fields to include in the result. This parameter is optional, and if omitted, all fields will be included in the result.

In Python, you could do something like this:

```py
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

for x in mycol.find({},{ "_id": 0, "item_id": 0, "count": 1 }):
  print(x)
```

You are not allowed to specify both 0 and 1 values in the same object except if one of the fields is the `_id` field. If you specify a field with the value 0, all other fields get the value 1, and vice versa.